# Existence and uniqueness of the solutions of $\dot{x}(t)= - (x(t))^{1/3}$

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

For the IVP:
$
\left\{ \begin{array}{c} \dot{x}(t) = -x(t)^{1/3} \\ x(0)=x_0 \end{array}\right.
$
I am trying to prove existence and uniqueness and the maximal range of existence.

As $\dot{x}(t) = F(t,x(t)) = -(x^{1/3})$ is well-defined and continuous for all real $x$, except negative numbers since then the value of $F(t,x(t))$ would have to be complex, there exists a solution for $x\geq 0$.

As $\frac{\partial\,F(t,x(t))}{x} = \frac{-1}{3\,x^{2/3}}$ is well-defined and continuous only for positive values of $x$, then there is a unique solution for $x>0$.

I know of 3 solutions for $x=0$, and I see that the Picard-Lindel\"of theorem says that, assuming a Lipschitz condition is held, that a unique solution should hold for the $x>0$. Is solving the ode then the only method left to determine the maximal time of existence? (Because I have seen when this theorem gave an answer that was too narrow).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since any solution is such that $x(t)\geqslant0$ and $(x^{2/3})'(t)=-2/3$, the solutions when $x_0\gt0$ are exactly the functions such that $x(t)^{2/3}=x_0^{2/3}-2t/3$ for every $t\geqslant0$ small enough, that is, $x(t)=(x_0^{2/3}-2t/3)^{3/2}$ on the maximal interval $(-\infty,3x_0^{2/3}/2)$. If $x_0=0$, the unique solution is $x(t)=0$ and the maximal interval is $(-\infty,+\infty)$.

Comment: I guess I don't understand why, of the 3 solutions I found for $(t_0,x_0)=(0,0)$, $x(t)=0$ wouldn't be one of the solutions. $F(t,x(t))$ is continuous there, but $dF/dx$ is undefined so, assuming the Lipschitz condition holds, wouldn't there just be a loss of uniqueness there? I haven't calculated for a Lipschitz constant - is that why there are no solutions for $x_0=0$ (I am doing it now)?

Comment: The previous version was not correct, see revised version.

Comment: Oh, I cannot even apply $|f(x)-f(y)| \leq K\,|x-y|,\;\forall x,y \in 0 \ni E$ because $f(x<0)$ is not defined for real numbers. Hence it cannot be Lipschitz.

Comment: The function is not even Lipschitz on $(0,+\infty)$ since the derivative explodes when $x\to0^+$.

Comment: I get that... I guess because the Picard-Lindel\"of theorem is not "if and only if", just "if", then there could still be solutions that don't satisfy the Lipschitz criterion of the theorem... Right?

Comment: Yes. $ $ $ $ $ $

Comment: Ummm, one last thing. How do you know the solution to the IVP for $x(0)=0$ is unique, since the above stated theorem can't be used?

Comment: If $x_0=0$ there is also solution $x(t)=(-2/3t)^{3/2}$ on $(-\infty,0]$, hence the solution is not unique.

Comment: @nate For a separable equation the uniqueness can be determined by the fact that after the separation of variables the corresponding integrals are divergent.

Comment: I found that one too... I'll have to think about your helpful comment regarding the divergence. :)